# Finding two sublists of fixed sizes (K,L) to maximize total sum among positive sequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

Given a list of positive integers, and two integers *K* and *L*, I need to select two non-overlapping contiguous sublists of lengths *K* and *L* so as to maximize the combined sum of the two sublists.

For example, if the list is [6,1,4,6,3,2,7,4], *K* = 3, and *L* = 2, then I want the sublists [4,6,3] and [7,4], whose combined sum of 24 is the maximum achievable.

The list has at least *K* + *L* elements and at most 600 elements; the elements are integers in the range [1, 500].

I do not know where to start. I'm thinking a Dynamic Programming solution, but I'm not very familiar with it so I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

Comment: The important part of problem description seem to disappear. Please double check.

Comment: it's been fixed. thanks.

Comment: Just an idea: sort the numbers and then pick the largest K+L numbers.

Comment: @dhanushka Once the numbers are sorted, the subsets are not contiguous anymore.

Comment: @user58697 Oh, I missed that part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan array left to right, calculating partial sums for continuous subarrays of length K and of length L starting at every index. It might be performed in O(n).

Write the largest sums **before** each index to auxiliary arrays `LeftK, LeftL`

Write the largest sums **after** each index to auxiliary arrays `RightK, RightL`

Now for every index `i` get sums of `LeftK[i]+RightL[i]` and `LeftL[i]+RightK[i]` and choose the best sum among all entries.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement it.